# Is it possible to get the timezone of a Sharepoint site programmatically using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

Is it possible to get the timezone of a Sharepoint site programmatically using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client in C#? I need the Sharepoint site timezone to match it with a particular timezone.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately for the Client Side Object Model of SharePoint it is not possible to get the timezone perse. Server Object Model and SPServices contains a property for SPWeb called RegionalSettings, however this is lacking in CSOM.

The good thing here is that CSOM has a Utility feature called `FormatDateTime` which you can use to convert a specific string/date to the timezone of your site.

Below is an example of it's use in a simple console application:

```
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://yoursite.com");
        Site site = clientContext.Site;

        DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("04/24/2013 5:44PM").ToUniversalTime();
        ClientResult<string> cr = Utility.FormatDateTime(clientContext, clientContext.Web, dt, DateTimeFormat.DateTime);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        string value = cr.ToString();
        DateTime webdt = DateTime.Parse(cr.Value.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(webdt.ToString());
        Console.Read();
```

Take note that you need to have the SharePoint Client DLLs included in the project as well as referencing them properly. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext(yourSite);
var culture = context.Web.RegionalSettings;
context.Load(culture);
var tz = culture.TimeZone;
context.Load(tz);
context.ExecuteQuery();
context.Dispose();
```

tz will contain your timezone, bias, etc..

Comment: RegionalSettings is not a property of ClientContext.Web. This code snippet gives me a syntax error. And of course I've referenced the  Sharepoint Client DLLs.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.regionalsettings.aspx
The fact you did not find it is probably because you are using SP2010.

Answer (score 0):

My code is similar to Deptor's, but I think my code fixes a few syntax issues I had when I tried running it on my SP 2013 site. I also use some global variables to store things like the ClientContext, Web, Culture, and Timezone SP CSOM objects to help learners understand what each object contains.

Code:

```
var context, web, culture, tz;

var siteTzId, siteTzDesc, siteTzInformation;

getSiteRegionalTimeZone();

setTimeout(function(){
    alert("Site TZ = |"+ siteTzDesc +"|");
}, 2000);

function getSiteRegionalTimeZone() {
    context = new SP.ClientContext();
    web = context.get_web();
    culture = web.get_regionalSettings();
    context.load(culture);
    tz = culture.get_timeZone();
    context.load(tz);
    context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
        siteTzId = tz.$5_0.$H_0.Id;
        siteTzDesc = tz.$5_0.$H_0.Description;
        siteTzInformation = tz.$5_0.$H_0.Information;
    });
    context.dispose();
};
```